# MAXIMO API 7.6.1 POST to create service requests programmatically creates null records, but the same work in POSTMAN

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, maximo, maximo-anywhere

I am trying to use MAXIMO 7.6.1 API to create requests in MAXIMO through POST requests programmatically.

**Problem 1:**

The problem is, though the POST is successful .i.e I am getting a 201.

Only null records are being created.

However the same request when done using POSTMAN works perfectly.

**Here is my programmatic implementation:**

```
    var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(somemodel);
    string MaximoUrl = @"someurl/maxrest/oslc/os/mxapisr";
    WebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(MaximoUrl);
    request.Headers["authheaderkey"] = "authheadervalue";
    request.Headers["properties"] = "*";
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";

    using (var RequestStream = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                RequestStream.Write(jsonData);
            }

            string ResponseResult;

            HttpWebResponse RequestResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            using (var ResponseReader = new StreamReader(RequestResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                ResponseResult = ResponseReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

*The above creates a record but creates null records.*

**Same in POSTMAN:**
[image: request Headers]

[image: Request body]

**Problem 2:**

When I include query string parameters in the request url I get a 400 Bad Request. 
Again, the same works in POSTMAN.

This works:

> string MaximoUrl = @"someurl/maxrest/oslc/os/mxapisr";

This doesn't:

> string MaximoUrl = @"someurl/maxrest/oslc/os/mxapisr?lean=1";

I believe this is a problem with how MAXIMO understands requests.

model being sent:

```
public class obj
    {
        public Int64 ticketuid { get; set; }

        public string ticketid { get; set; }

        public string description { get; set; }

        public string reportedby { get; set; }

        public int rc { get; set; }

        public string workt { get; set; }

        public string ownergroup { get; set; }

        public string siteid { get; set; }

        public string reportedemail { get; set; }

        public string affectedemail { get; set; }

        public DateTime? changedate { get; set; }

        public DateTime? affecteddate { get; set; }

        public DateTime? reportdate { get; set; }

        public DateTime? statusdate { get; set; }

        public DateTime? desireddate { get; set; }

        public string description_longdescription { get; set; }

        public string assetnum { get; set; }

        public string location { get; set; }

        public string status { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: I assume you correctly use the MAXAUTH header prop to authenticate?
https://developer.ibm.com/static/site-id/155/maximodev/restguide/Maximo_Nextgen_REST_API.html#_maximo_asset_management_native_authentication

Comment: It looks like Maximo cannot map the fields in the request's body to the included fields in your Maximo object structure thus creating an empty record. Adding the body to the details of your question would help.

Comment: I am able to successfully authenticate and also create requests in maximo through the API. The problem is in the body, the JSON body I am giving doesn't reflect. Only null records are being created.

Comment: Sure will add it :)

Comment: Have added the model I am sending in the body.

Comment: I have used the same model in a GET, and am able to successfully bind the same response.

Comment: If you don't provide the lean=1 parameter Maximo will look for the namespace for each field which is probably why every field ends null.

Comment: could you make it work?

Comment: @JPTremblay lean=1 did the trick, cannot believe how I could miss it :)
If you write an answer , I can accept it :)
Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the Maximo REST API to create objects in Maximo, don't forget to use the *lean* flag. If you don't specify this parameter you need to qualify each attribute with its namespace in your request's body.

Example without *lean* flag:

```
http://maximohost/maximo/oslc/os/MXASSET
```

Without the lean flag you'd need to provide the namespace for each attribute:

```
 {
        "spi:assetnum": "PUMP01",
        "spi:description": "Some Pump",
        "spi:siteid": "BEDFORD"
 }
```

And if you don't provide the namespace qualifier you'll get empty records because Maximo won't be able to map any of the attributes in your request's body with the object structure's definition.

Also, make sure that the attributes that you want to set are not excluded at the object structure level.

Ref.: https://developer.ibm.com/static/site-id/155/maximodev/restguide/Maximo_Nextgen_REST_API.html

Comment: yep, i can approve of this answer. we had similar issue that made us scratch our heads for a while. esp. because maximo won't give you any meaningful error (or any at all!)

Comment: Just worked for me! Thanks, IBM, for terrible error messaging as per usual! lol